# Como recupero a data atual de um banco MySQL no Arduino?

Tags: mysql, c, arduino

Estou fazendo conexão com banco de dados `mysql` usando o arduino junto ao esp8266, queria saber como pegar data atual armazenar em uma variavel para depois mandar ao banco. Estou com problemas apenas para pegar a data atual.

Comment: Se vai mandar apenas para o banco, não é mais fácil o banco pegar direto a data?

Comment: No caso, para o banco pegar direto a data teria que usar trigger?

Comment: Não. Se for apenas armazenar, poderia ser algo como `current()` ou `now()`, dependendo de qual banco é.

Comment: blz, agradeço a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `MySQL` possui uma função de manipulação de data e hora chamada [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), que por sua vez, é capaz de retornar a data e a hora do banco de dados representados pela quantidade de segundos que se passaram desde a [Era Unix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) (Desde às 00:00hrs do dia 1 de Janeiro de 1970):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

Em `C`, o tipo [`time_t`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t), definido pela biblioteca padrão [`time.h`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time.h) tem o propósito de armazenar, o intervalo de tempo em segundos, desde a [Era Unix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix).

Juntando as duas coisas, você poderia implementar uma função mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

time_t obterDataHoraBD( MySQL_Connection * pconn )
{
  row_values * row = NULL;
  time_t t = 0;

  MySQL_Cursor * cur = new MySQL_Cursor( pconn );
  cur->execute( "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();" );
  row = cur->get_next_row();
  t = atol( row->values[0] );
  delete cur;

  return t;
}
```

Para converter um `time_t` para algo humanamente legível, você pode usar as funções `localtime()` e `gmtime()` que retornam uma [`struct tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm):

```
struct tm                                                                                                
{                                                                                                   
   int tm_sec;           /* Seconds. [0-60] (1 leap second) */      
   int tm_min;           /* Minutes. [0-59] */                            
   int tm_hour;          /* Hours.   [0-23] */                       
   int tm_mday;          /* Day.     [1-31] */             
   int tm_mon;           /* Month.   [0-11] */                
   int tm_year;          /* Year - 1900.  */                       
   int tm_wday;          /* Day of week. [0-6] */                 
   int tm_yday;          /* Days in year.[0-365] */                        
   int tm_isdst;         /* DST.     [-1/0/1]*/         
}
```

Você também pode usar a função `ctime()`, que recebe um `time_t` e retorna um ponteiro para uma string contendo a data e a hora no seguinte formato:

```
"Thu Jun 21 08:27:33 2018\n"
```

Segue um código demonstrativo aplicando as ideias:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

EthernetClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn( (Client*) &client );

byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress local_ip( 192, 168, 1, 123 );

IPAddress server_addr( 192, 168, 1, 1 );
int port = 3306;

char user[] = "nome_usaurio";
char password[] = "senha";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);

  Ethernet.begin( mac_addr, local_ip );

  conn.connect( server_addr, port, user, password );
}

time_t obterDataHoraBD( MySQL_Connection * pconn )
{
  row_values * row = NULL;
  time_t t = 0;

  MySQL_Cursor * cur = new MySQL_Cursor( pconn );
  cur->execute( "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());" );
  row = cur->get_next_row();
  t = atol( row->values[0] );
  delete cur;

  return t;
}

void loop()
{
    time_t datahora = obterDataHoraBD( &conn );

    Serial.print( "UNIX Epoch= " );
    Serial.println( datahora );

    Serial.write( "Data/Hora= " );
    Serial.println( ctime(datahora) );

    delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Não existe biblioteca nem API no Arduino para banco de dados e, se existir, não devem estar sendo usadas do jeito que você demonstrou.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura: Existe sim, se chama [MySQL_Connector_Arduino](https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino).

Comment: @MarceloUchimura: Segue edição demonstrando uma conexão e uma consulta a um banco MySQL usando uma interface Ethernet.

Comment: na 6a. linha, `MySQL_Connection conn( (Client*) &client );`, não deveria ser `MYSQL_Connection conn;`?

Comment: O objeto de conexao deve ser criado somente após a inicializacao da inteface de Ethernet. `client` é o objeto global que representa essa interface conectada na rede.